# Transient component is registered as transient but implements idisposable

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, simple-injector

I use Simple injector but somehow i get error as stated in subject. I tried many things before i decided to post this question for instance this is not working for me. I get the following exception when I call `Validate`:

Validation error message:

> The configuration is invalid. The following diagnostic warnings were reported:
>
> -[Disposable Transient Component] AlbumsController is registered as transient, but implements IDisposable.
>
> -[Disposable Transient Component] ArtistsController is registered as transient, but implements IDisposable.
>
> -[Disposable Transient Component] HomeController is registered as transient, but implements IDisposable.
>
> See the Error property for detailed information about the warnings. Please see https://simpleinjector.org/diagnostics how to fix problems and how to suppress individual warnings.

**Application_Start**

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

    container = new Container();
    container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new WebRequestLifestyle();
    container.Register<IRepository<Artist>, ArtistRepository>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
    container.Register<IRepository<Album>, AlbumRepository>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
    container.RegisterMvcControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
    container.Verify();
    DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new SimpleInjectorDependencyResolver(container));
}
```

[image: Visual Studio Debugger hitting on the exception thrown by Verify]

I tried to add `Lifestyle.Scoped` to my registrations as follows:

```
container.Register<IRepository<Artist>, ArtistRepository>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
container.Register<IRepository<Album>, AlbumRepository>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
```

**Controllers:**

Note: Repositories implement `IDisposable`.

```
public class HomeController : Controller 
{
    ...
}

public class AlbumsController : Controller 
{
    readonly IRepository<Album> _repository;

    public AlbumsController(IRepository<Album> repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }

    ...
}
```

Other details:

- My controllers do *not* override the `protected virtual void Dispose(bool)` method.
- I'm using Simple Injector v4.4.0
- I'm using the web integration packages v3.2.7

Comment: Please can you post the stack trace as text, not everyone can see linked images?

Comment: @qujck pasted all information including stack trace

Comment: The stacktrace talks about xxxController. The information about the repositories is irrelevant. Does your HomeController, etc. inherit Controller?

Comment: @Ric.Net is right. Please post the relevant code for one of your controllers, such as the `HomeController`. The most likely cause is that your controller classes (or their base class) overrides `protected void Dispose(bool)` from the `Controller` base class.

Comment: @Steven i added more code for you. Note that i implemented IDisposable in Repository class because i thought it has to be done according to error. Should i remove it?

Comment: Hi @Henry: From the posted code, it is unclear what the problem is. Please reduce the code to the least possible amount of lines. This can be done best by creating a new empty solution and adding code step by step until the problem appears. After that, reduce as much code as you can without the problem disappearing. The code that will be left is the code that you should post as [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Steven i reduced the code. If anything more is needed let me know. All controllers inherits from Controller class. All controllers's repositories classes implements IDisposable.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I am unable to reproduce the issue you are having. Are you using the latest version of Simple Injector? If not, please upgrade and try again. If this doesn't solve the problem, it means your example is not an MCVE. For it to be an MCVE, anyone should be able to reproduce the issue using the code you provided.

Comment: @Steven i will check, nevertheless simpleinjector's code looks fine from what you see ?

Comment: Yes, your SI registrations look fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the supplied demo project I was indeed able to reproduce the issue.

The problem is in the referenced packages:

```xml
<package id="SimpleInjector" version="4.4.0" targetFramework="net46" />
<package id="SimpleInjector.Integration.Web" version="3.2.7" targetFramework="net46" />
<package id="SimpleInjector.Integration.Web.Mvc" version="3.2.7" targetFramework="net46" />
```

As you can see the packages for MVC are from another major branch.

If you update everything to 4.4.0 your problem goes away.

Apart from this, the error message is *not* telling you to implement `IDisposable` in your repositories. SimpleInjector, and any other tool for that matter, is not able to decide this for you.

You should decide for yourself if you need that. If you would also inject the `DbContext`, which is best practice anyway, there is no need to implement `IDisposable` at all in your repository assuming the current implementations won't change much.

Comment: You mean always all simpleinjector libraries has to be from same version?

Comment: I would say yes, but at least from the same major version. Is there any concern why you would not want to reference v4 of the web packages?

Comment: There's not nevertheless would like to know why the case. Since i installed simpleinjector from nuget i wonder why installed versions was diffrent that's why of my current concerns. Cheers man.

Comment: Haven;t notice that before. I see now :)

Comment: After some deep analysis, @Ric.Net and I figured out that the DiagnosticType enumeration was changed in v4, causing its values to accidentally get renumbered. Because C# compiles these values down to hardcoded integers, the v3 integration package just referred to value `6`, which in v4 causes a different suppression (i.e. AmbiguousLifestyles). So there are two things I did wrong here: 1. forget to number enum values in the code base, 2. forget to restrict NuGet package dependencies to the same major release.