# Simple Injector: Setting Lifestyle to Scoped does not fix Disposable Transient Components error

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, simple-injector

I am calling a WCF service in my Web API project and am struggling to get it registered correctly. I had it working at one point but I suspect a nuget update has changed things. I now get a Disposable Transient Component error on verify even though I've set the registration type to Lifestyle.Scoped.

Additionally per this post I have checked the versions and they are all on the same version. [Transient component is registered as transient but implements idisposable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53484944/transient-component-is-registered-as-transient-but-implements-idisposable)

```
<package id="SimpleInjector" version="4.6.0" targetFramework="net472" />
<package id="SimpleInjector.Integration.WebApi" version="4.6.0" targetFramework="net472" />
<package id="SimpleInjector.Integration.WebApi.WebHost.QuickStart" version="4.6.0" targetFramework="net472" />
```

Here is my code:

```
        public static void Initialize()
        {
            var container = new Container();

            // Lifestyle set as per recommended for API:
            // https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetimes.html#asyncscoped-vs-webrequest
            container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new AsyncScopedLifestyle();

            container.Options.UseFullyQualifiedTypeNames = true;

            InitializeContainer(container);

            container.RegisterWebApiControllers(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);

            container.Verify();

            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver =
                new SimpleInjectorWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
        }


        private static void InitializeContainer(Container container)
        {
            // WCF            
            container.Register<IServices>(() => new ServiceClient("endpoint"), Lifestyle.Scoped);
        }
```

Exception:

> Exception thrown: 'SimpleInjector.DiagnosticVerificationException' in SimpleInjector.dll
>   An exception of type 'SimpleInjector.DiagnosticVerificationException' occurred in SimpleInjector.dll but was not handled in user code
>   The configuration is invalid. The following diagnostic warnings were reported:
>   -[Disposable Transient Component] Container is registered as transient, but implements IDisposable.
>   See the Error property for detailed information about the warnings. Please see https://simpleinjector.org/diagnostics how to fix problems and how to suppress individual warnings.

It seems as if it is ignoring the Lifestyle.Scoped. Any thoughts?

Second Exception:

> Exception thrown: 'SimpleInjector.DiagnosticVerificationException' in SimpleInjector.dll
>   An exception of type 'SimpleInjector.DiagnosticVerificationException' occurred in SimpleInjector.dll but was not handled in user code
>   The configuration is invalid. The following diagnostic warnings were reported:
>   -[Disposable Transient Component] Container is registered as transient, but implements IDisposable.
>   See the Error property for detailed information about the warnings. Please see https://simpleinjector.org/diagnostics how to fix problems and how to suppress individual warnings.

Comment: Please post the complete exception message.

Comment: Updated with Exception

Comment: Please set `container.Options.UseFullyQualifiedTypeNames = true;` in your example, run the code again, and add the new exception message to your question.

Comment: I added the UseFullyQualifiedTypeNames set to true and added the newest exception. It appears to be the same exception as before.

Comment: It seems you registered a type called `Container` as transient, but this registration is not shown in your question. This means your question is not a MCVE and I'm unable to reproduce your issue. You should find out where you register that Container. Note that if you are registering the Simple Injector container into itself, this is not needed as it is done automatically and using the Singleton lifestyle.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I added the complete methods for Intialize and InitializeContainer. (Before 'fix')  If I add ```container.Options.DefaultLifestyle = new AsyncScopedLifestyle();``` right after ```container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new AsyncScopedLifestyle();``` It stops complaining and is working.  However, is this the best Lifestyle option for an API setup?

Comment: You might have run into a bug. Unfortunately, I'm unable to reproduce the issue. Would you mind creating an (MVCE) example that reproduces the issue and posting it here: https://github.com/simpleinjector/SimpleInjector/issues/new/.

Comment: Thank you for your questions they lead me down the right path. It was user error. For some reason I decided to pass Container to one of the constructors and that was the root cause. I removed Container from the constructor and everything worked fine.

Comment: Even when you inject `SimpleInjector.Container` into one of your classes, you should not get that "transient disposable" exception. I'm still interested in a repro. Or did you inject your own custom class named `Container`?

Comment: I did not inject a custom Container. Interesting. I was having trouble recreating it - I'll see what I can do.